# NAND gate from BJTs: interfacing +/- 12v op-amp and 5v logic: destroy BJT with excessive Vebo?

Tags: bjt, 12v, 5v, resistor-transistor-logic

I want to switch on a relay when both a 5v logic input is high and a (LM741 used as a) comparator is around +10v, and the circuit I planned to use is below.

The problem I see with the circuit is when `BUF1` output is low, (0v) and `OA1` output is low, (-10v) the base of `Q1` will be at 0v, but the emitter will be floating. Could this destroy Q1, given that `Vebo` absolute maximum for BC547A is 6v?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB1prs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't destroy — or even stress — Q1.

Remember, the base-emitter junction of a transistor is just a diode, after all. If there's no external connection to the emitter (e.g., when Q2 is cut off), then it simply sits about 0.65V below whatever the base voltage is.

The V<sub>EBO</sub> specification applies only when you're deliberately reverse-biasing that diode, which, because of the doping of that junction for good transistor action, has a very low breakdown voltage.